# Regular expression - String start with and end with anything (but something)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to make a redirection URL in htaccess.
I want to redirect URLs like
www.domain.com/marques.phpANYTHINGIUYFUID
to
www.domain.com/marques.php

I tried that but does not work
...

```
RewriteRule ^marques.php([0-9]+)([A-Z]+)(/)?$ / [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(marques\.php).+$ /$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Perfect and super fast answer! Thx :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
RewriteRule ^marques\.php.+$ / [R=301]
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]